# Can Jenkins detect browser type.If then how can we pass it to the automation script to run?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to get the browser type in Jenkins.If then how can we pass it to the automation script to run

Comment: Jenkins can't detect the browser type , but you add a parameter to your build script browser type.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if a software is installed in linux using the following command

```
user@dumy:~$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
user@dumy:~$ which google-chrome 
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Based on this you will know the location of the installation directory and if you wish to know the version then you can add the following command

```
google-chrome --version
```

Now in Jenkins you can do a Pipeline and run shell script commands using simple if conditions and pass the value as an argument to your shell script